# SQL statement timing out on large data set

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

Trying to complete a web process, I'm getting the error `canceling statement due to statement timeout`. Debugging the codebase it turns out that the below query is timing out due to large data set. I appreciate any suggestions on how to increase the below query performance.

```
select userid, max(recent_activity_date) recent_activity_date 
from (
      SELECT id AS userid,
        recent_logged_in AS recent_activity_date
      FROM user
      WHERE recent_logged_in > now() - cast('10 days' AS INTERVAL)
      UNION
      SELECT userid AS userid, max(recentaccessed) AS recent_activity_date
      FROM tokencreds
      WHERE recentaccessed > now() - cast('10 days' AS INTERVAL)
      GROUP BY userid
) recent_activity 
  WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from user where id = userid and not deleted) 
  group by userid 
  order by userid;
```

Index per table:

- Table **user**:
  `user_recent_logged_in on user (recent_logged_in)`
- Table **tokencreds**: `tokencreds_userid_token on tokencreds (userid, token)`. **tokencreds_userid_token** is unique.

Comment: It might be smart to include an [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-explain.html) for your query, and maybe even explain why you do `GROUP BY ownerid`

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for your comments. I have updated my question. I'm grouping by userid - `GROUP BY userid` instead.

Comment: Include what indexes you have on the tables too.

Comment: Since you have the `EXISTS(user_id)` you can replace the `UNION` by a `JOIN`. And you probably need `GREATEST()`

Comment: @Stu I have included the indexes in the question. Please, have a look.

Comment: BTW: `user` is a keyword in (postgres) SQL. Try to avoid using it for a table- or column name.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `union`, and the `exists()`, and combine them into a straight `join`:

---

```
SELECT x.userid
        , GREATEST(x.recent_logged_in, x.recent_activity_date ) AS recent_activity_date
FROM (
      SELECT u.id AS userid
        , u.recent_logged_in
        , MAX(t.recentaccessed) AS recent_activity_date
      FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN tokencreds AS t ON t.userid = u.id
      WHERE NOT u.deleted  
      AND (
        u.recent_logged_in > now() - cast('10 days' AS INTERVAL)
        OR t.recentaccessed > now() - cast('10 days' AS INTERVAL)
        )
      GROUP BY u.id
        ) x
  ORDER by userid;
```

Comment: Small remark: this does require that there is a `tokencreds` record for each `userid`; which probably is the case but just maybe not, just pointing out. You also risk exploding your data if `userids` have many `token`s  assigned to it. Otherwise I do like learning about `GREATEST()`, thx =)

Comment: Well, you could make it a LEFT join. [BTW: your `exists()` will exclude all tokencreeds that don't have a corresponding userid]

Comment: True, but so is the OP, right? (or at least I think that's the point of the bottom `WHERE EXISTS()` there even though it's not entirely correct [id/userid]?)

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the 'layout' of your data. Are there a lot of records 'hit'? Are there a lot of records in users? in tokencreds? etc...

Personally I would go for this:

```
SELECT userid, max(recent_activity_date) recent_activity_date _user
 FROM (
        SELECT id AS userid, MAX(recent_logged_in) AS recent_activity_date
          FROM user
         WHERE recent_logged_in > now() - cast('10 days' AS INTERVAL)
           AND NOT deleted
         UNION ALL
        SELECT userid AS userid, MAX(recentaccessed) AS recent_activity_date
          FROM tokencreds
         WHERE recentaccessed > now() - cast('10 days' AS INTERVAL)
           AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = userid AND NOT deleted)
) recent_activity 
  GROUP BY userid 
  ORDER BY userid; 
  
  
 -- indexes 'needed' on :
 CREATE INDEX idx_userid_not_deleted ON user (userid) WHERE NOT deleted;
 CREATE INDEX idx_recent_logged_in_user_id_not_deleted ON user (recent_logged_in, userid) WHERE not deleted;
 CREATE INDEX idx_recentaccessed_user_id ON tokencreds (recentaccessed, userid);
```

but YMMV. **To get a better idea you really should provide the full EXPLAIN ANALYZE result otherwise we're just flying blind and guessing here**. Could be the system will refuse to use any of the suggested indexes in which case you better remove then again off course.

Reasoning:

- the `UNION` will cause an implicit distinct on the sub-select which you don't really need as te `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` later on will pretty much do the same so why do things twice?
- better to filter 'as soon as possible' rather then filter in the end IMHO (**)

**: Do note that the results here ARE going to be different! (but I think mine are 'better'). E.g. suppose you have 3 records for user_id 5

- user_id = 5, deleted = true, recent_activity_date = Dec 10
- user_id = 5, deleted = false, recent_activity_date = Dec 8
- user_id = 5, deleted = false, recent_activity_date = Dec 5

Ignoring the `tokencreds` table, the result for user_id 5 will be Dec 10 in your version while in mine it will be Dec 8. Check your requirements on which one you want!

edit: mistake in suggested indexes